# How to type mex(minimum excludent)?

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing about combinatorial game theory and need to typeset mex in math mode. Any ideas? I don't know what command should I use, nor which package contains this command. I tried \mex but doesn't seemed like it works.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Your question is vague. Could you please explain your situation better? Do you want advice on packages to use?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a macro called, say, `\mex`, that looks very much like `\max`?

Comment: Something `\mex` like into this site? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)

Comment: @InigoM Done....!! The site is very very nice, you can find everything you need knowing it a little bit more. And then I also recommend you to read online guides or pdf on the use of LaTeX. Greetings.

Comment: @Sebastiano I'm new to both Latex and S.E. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just any formulas of the site https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics) using `\DeclareMathOperator{\mex}{mex}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mex}{mex}
\begin{document}

\[\mex(\emptyset) = 0, \quad
\mex(\{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, \omega\}) = \omega+1\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks!